# result of torch.multinomial is affected by the first-dim size

Tags: pytorch

The code is as below, given the same seed, just comment out one line, the result will change.

I think the second output should be `[[2],[0]]`, but got  `[[0],[2]]` instead.

Can anyone tell me why?

```py
import torch
torch.manual_seed(1)
logits = torch.tensor([
    [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4],
    [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
])
print(torch.multinomial(logits, 1))

torch.manual_seed(1)
logits = torch.tensor([
    # [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4],
    [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1],
    [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4],
])
print(torch.multinomial(logits, 1))

# the results are
# tensor([[3],
#         [2],
#         [0]])
# tensor([[0],
#         [2]])
```